# select tag is automaticaly closed on click

Tags: jquery, select

click on `left` and click on `sela`. It is open and automatically closed. What is the reason?

```js
$('#left').on('click', function() {
  $('.sela').appendTo($(this));
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 9px;
  height: 120px;
}

.left {
  background: silver;
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  background: gold;
}

.sela {
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left' id='left'></div>
  <div class='right'>323</div>
</div>

<select class='sela'>
  <option>lorem</option>
  <option>ipsum</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every click on `#left`, the `select` tag will be removed from its previous location in the DOM (which will destroy current user interactions with it) and be appended to the new location. If the new location is the same place as it was originally, then it'll just nullify the current click interaction - which isn't what you want.

You might only `.append` if the event's target is *not* the `.sela`:

```js
$('#left').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.sela'))
    $('.sela').appendTo($(this));
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 9px;
  height: 120px;
}

.left {
  background: silver;
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  background: gold;
}

.sela {
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left' id='left'></div>
  <div class='right'>323</div>
</div>

<select class='sela'>
  <option>lorem</option>
  <option>ipsum</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script instead of your script.

```
$('#left').on('click', function(e) {
      if (!e.target.matches('.sela'))
          $('.sela').appendTo($(this));
 });
```

Always check whether the select is there on the same div or not. Otherwise, it will place your select to left div on your every click inside the left div.

Comment: @qadenza, after I posted only my page got refreshed. then only I have seen that comment. I just tried to help only. so just leave it. I will delete.

Comment: once you have seen the comment just respond. i have to delete my answer

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative -

You can remove the click 'event' after it is clicked first time.

```js
$('#left').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.sela').appendTo($(this));
    $(this).off('click');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 9px;
  height: 120px;
}

.left {
  background: silver;
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  background: gold;
}

.sela {
  position: absolute;
  right: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='left' id='left'></div>
  <div class='right'>323</div>
</div>
          
<select class='sela'>
  <option>lorem</option>
  <option>ipsum</option>
</select>
```